# What does ‘knock’ mean in this sentence

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

> “Boston has seven daily newspapers at the time, and the Molasses Flood is so big for about a week that it **knocks** off the front page the Prohibition amendment which essentially passes the night of the Molasses Flood, and it **knocks** the Versailles peace talks, the talks that ended World War I, off the front page, so it’s an enormous story in Boston at the time,” described Puleo.

<sup>*[Remembering The Great Boston Molasses Flood, 100 Years Later](https://nenc.news/remembering-the-great-boston-molasses-flood-100-years-later/)*</sup>

I am having trouble understanding this sentence. What does ‘knock’ mean in this sentence?

Comment: to knock off = [to remove by pushing, hitting, or other forceful action](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/knock-off-something?q=knock+off+%28something%29)

Comment: Welcome to the site! I don't thing the text is well worded or punctuated.  Even as a native speaker, it took me a second or two to parse it.

Comment: Do you know any meanings of "knock"? Have you checked a dictionary for more? Please show us what you already know so we don't waste our time and yours by telling you things you already know.

Answer (score 2):

[The very first definition in Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/knock) is appropriate:

> 1 : to strike something with a sharp blow

It's a metaphorical usage: the news about the molasses flood comes in and shoves Prohibition and Versailles off the front page of the newspaper.

Answer (score 2):

To knock X off Y means to dramatically remove X from Y.

The flood was so significant that it went to the front page of the newspapers, and thus took stories about WW1 off the front page.